# Why do I get a Segmentation Error in my C++ Base Converter?

Tags: c++

I am a student in c++, we have started 3 weeks ago. Our assignment is to make a Base Converter without using stoi or atol. We are using a site called Repl.it. I am getting an error called Segmentation Error with doesn't make sense. It started with stringToDecmial. We are referring to the Ascii Table by the way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int strToDecimal(int base, string num);

string decimalToBase(int number, int base);

int main()
{
  int menuChoice;

  int startBase;

  int numberInDecimal;

  string number;

  cout << "NUMBER BASE CONVERTER 2019" << endl;
  cout << "By: Suraj Joshi" << endl << endl;

  cout << "Enter number to convert: ";
  cin >> number;

  cout << "Choose your starting base: " << endl
       << "1. Binary" << endl
       << "2. Octal" << endl
       << "3. Decimal" << endl
       << "4. Hex" << endl;

  cin >> menuChoice;

  switch (menuChoice)
  {
    case 1: {
      startBase = 2;
      break;
    }
    case 2: {
      startBase = 8;
      break;
    }
    case 3: {
      startBase = 10;
      break;
    }
    case 4: {
      startBase = 16;
      break;
    }
    default: {
      startBase = 0;
      cout << "Invalid Choice..." << endl;
      break;
    }
  }

  numberInDecimal = strToDecimal(startBase, number);

  cout << "Binary: " << decimalToBase(numberInDecimal, 2) << endl;
  cout << "Decimal: " << numberInDecimal << endl;
  cout << "Octal: " << decimalToBase(numberInDecimal, 8) << endl;
  cout << "Hex: " << decimalToBase(numberInDecimal, 16) << endl;

  return 0;
}

// This is where the problem starts(I Believe) I never experianced the problem
// when this wasnt here
int strToDecimal(int base, string num)
{
  int sum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; num.length() - 1; ++i) {
    if (num[i] > 64)

      sum += (num[i] - 55) * pow(base, num.length() - 1 - i);

    else

      sum += (num[i] - 48) * pow(base, num.length() - 1 - i);
  }

  return sum;
}

// this can be ingored, This isnt what is causing the problem but feel free to
// look at it, it isnt complete yet
string decimalToBase(int number, int base) {
  int rem;
  string tempStr(1, number % base + 48);

  while (number != 0) {
    rem = number % base;
    number = number / base;

    // str.insert(0, string(1, num % base + 48))
    // or string tempStr (1, num % base + 48);
    // str.insert(0, tempStr);

    switch (rem) {}  // switch

  }  // while

  return " ";
}
```

Comment: Your for-loop condition check is not checking any conditions? It just generates a temporary. I think you wanted: `i < num.length()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segmentation fault is because you're reading past the end of the `num` string. In your `strToDecimal` function this line

```cpp
  for (int i = 0; num.length() - 1; ++i) {
```

does not perform the right termination check. As long as `num.length() - 1` contains a non-zero value the loop will continue indefinately. You probably want to change it to:

```cpp
  for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); ++i) {
```